# Python psycopg2 returning False when pgadmin returns True

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have a python function in which I want to check if a PostgreSQL table exists or not (True, False)

it does not return True... even when I am logged into the same DB and checking in PGAdmin4.. and getting True.

Am I missing a commit?  I tried adding a `commit()` to no effect.

```
def __exists_table(self, table_name):
    cursor = self.__get_a_cursor()

    try:
        string_to_execute = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public' AND tablename = '" + table_name + "');"

        cursor.execute(string_to_execute)

        query_results = cursor.fetchall()
        if len(query_results) > 1:
            print("__exists_data got back multiple results, using the first")
        query_results = query_results[0][0]

        return query_results
    except Exception as err:
        print("Exception on __exists_table: " + str(err))
        raise err
    finally:
        cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears to work as written.

I have a database that contains a single table, `table1`:

```
$ psql -h localhost
psql (11.6, server 12.1 (Debian 12.1-1.pgdg100+1))
Type "help" for help.

lars=> \d
        List of relations
 Schema |  Name  | Type  | Owner
--------+--------+-------+-------
 public | table1 | table | lars
(1 row)
```

If I wrap your code up in a runnable script, like this:

```
import psycopg2


class DBTest:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = psycopg2.connect('host=localhost dbname=lars password=secret')

    def __get_a_cursor(self):
        return self.db.cursor()

    def __exists_table(self, table_name):
        cursor = self.__get_a_cursor()

        try:
            string_to_execute = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public' AND tablename = '" + table_name + "');"

            cursor.execute(string_to_execute)

            query_results = cursor.fetchall()
            if len(query_results) > 1:
                print("__exists_data got back multiple results, using the first")
            query_results = query_results[0][0]

            return query_results
        except Exception as err:
            print("Exception on __exists_table: " + str(err))
            raise err
        finally:
            cursor.close()

    def test_exists_table(self, table_name):
        return self.__exists_table(table_name)


db = DBTest()
for table_name in ['table1', 'table2']:
    if db.test_exists_table(table_name):
        print(f'{table_name} exists')
    else:
        print(f'{table_name} does not exist')
```

Running it produces the output I would expect:

```
table1 exists
table2 does not exist
```

---

Having said that, I would make the follow change to your code. First, rather than creating your query string like this:

```
string_to_execute = """SELECT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables
  WHERE schemaname = 'public' 
    AND tablename = '""" + table_name + "');"

cursor.execute(string_to_execute)
```

I would let your database driver take care of parameter substitution for you:

```
string_to_execute = """SELECT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables
  WHERE schemaname = 'public' 
    AND tablename = %s
  )"""

cursor.execute(string_to_execute, (table_name,))
```

This is easier to read and safer, since it will properly quote any special character in the parameter.

Comment: It ended up working.. there was just a delay for some reason.. maybe I needed to close the cursor object or something. Thank you for confirming!